# Is there a way to create a dictionary by declaring variables that make up its key-value pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, key-value, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary that contains a unique ID, name, and birthday. This dictionary will act like a birthday database, and my challenge is that I couldn't figure out how to put multiple IDs in it.

```
db = {"id": 1, "fn": "JM", "ln" : "Cruz", "dob": "October 5, 1980"}
db1 = {"id": 2, "fn": "JD", "ln" : "Castillo", "dob": "August 18, 1979"}
db2 = {"id": 3, "fn": "Maria", "ln" : "Torres", "dob": "August 3, 1992"}

print("ID: " + str(db["id"]))
print("Full Name: " + db["fn"] + " " + db["ln"])
print("Birthday: " + db["dob"])
print("----------------------")
print("ID: " + str(db1["id"]))
print("Full Name: " + db1["fn"] + " " + db1["ln"])
print("Birthday: " + db1["dob"])
print("----------------------")
print("ID: " + str(db2["id"]))
print("Full Name: " + db2["fn"] + " " + db2["ln"])
print("Birthday: " + db2["dob"])
print("----------------------")
```

In the code above, you would notice how I had to repeat the creation of dictionaries just to be able to enumerate multiple sets of ID, name, and birthday. Is there a way that these keys be translated to a variable, and give the same output?

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking. Are you asking if there is a better container? One that will hold multiple values for each field and maintain the relationship between the field values?

Comment: Or are you asking if there is a way to automate making the dictionaries from pre-existing data?

Comment: My question has been answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a list for this purpose

```
dblist = []
dblist.append( {"id": 1, "fn": "JM", "ln" : "Cruz", "dob": "October 5, 1980"})
dblist.append( {"id": 2, "fn": "JD", "ln" : "Castillo", "dob": "August 18, 1979"})
dblist.append({"id": 3, "fn": "Maria", "ln" : "Torres", "dob": "August 3, 1992"})
for db in dblist:
    print("ID: " + str(db["id"]))
    print("Full Name: " + db["fn"] + " " + db["ln"])
    print("Birthday: " + db["dob"])
    print("----------------------")
```

OUTPUT

```
ID: 1
Full Name: JM Cruz
Birthday: October 5, 1980
----------------------
ID: 2
Full Name: JD Castillo
Birthday: August 18, 1979
----------------------
ID: 3
Full Name: Maria Torres
Birthday: August 3, 1992
----------------------
```

Comment: It's not necessary to init empty list and append constant values, just init it with that values.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I know , I was just  trying to show that the all the new dictionary the OP wants can be just append to this list.

Comment: If all this dictionary are constant the have to be added to list on initialization `lst = [itm0, itm1, itm2]` otherwise you'll do reallocate memory few times.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I told you, I was just trying to show you can add to the list with the append method . And besides the time difference is really negilibile.

Answer (score 0):

You can create only one `dict` and keys are user ID's. Other information like "fn, ln, dob" may be in the list. You'll append these 3 info in certain order, so you can retrieve any necessary info from the list.

Sample:

`db = {"1" : [fn1, ln1, dob1], "2": [fn2, ln2, dob2]}`

Comment: No reason to use `dict` here, cause there's `list` which created to store data and access to them by indexes.

Comment: @OlvinRoght No, she can reach data which is wanted to retrieve by using `key` in `O(1)` complexity, otherwise she must traverse the list in `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: You're not right, in python (and in 99,9% other languages) list/array has O(1) on get/set operations. [Python operations complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes you are right but I mean different things. Let me give a sample to you. Let's say user id's are = `1, 10, 32, 43` so if you `append` all of user id's first index is 1, second index is 10, third index is 32 and last index is 43. There is a problem when trying to access data. How can you know which user id's index? So, you should traverse the list from index zero to end of the list. But in `dict` you do not know indexes. Just access the data with user id.

Comment: Sample of data provided in question and question at all doesn't require what you're trying to explain me. Given task doesn't require using `dict`, even more - it slow down whole process, cause iteration over nested dict will be significantly more complex.

Comment: @OlvinRoght `dict.keys()` provides iteration of the dict

Comment: `dict.keys()` return iterator of keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
db = [{"id": 1, "fn": "JM", "ln" : "Cruz", "dob": "October 5, 1980"}, {"id": 2, "fn": "JD", "ln" : "Castillo", "dob": "August 18, 1979"}, {"id": 3, "fn": "Maria", "ln" : "Torres", "dob": "August 3, 1992"}]

for i in db:
    print(f"ID: {i['id']}\nFull Name: {i['fn']} {i['ln']}\nBirthday: {i['dob']}\n{'-' * 22}")
```

Or you can "play" with unpacking:

```
for i in db:
    print("ID: {}\nFull Name: {} {}\nBirthday: {}\n".format(*i.values()) + "-" * 22)
```